# DevExpress menu is not available after Visual Studio Community 2013 installation

Tags: visual-studio-2013, devexpress

Firstly, I installed the DevExpress 13.2.5 version. After that, I installed Visual Studio Community 2013 edition. But I cannot see the DevExpress menu item in the Visual Studio IDE menu. How can I bring the DevExpress menu item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to go through the below DevExpress Knowledge Base thread:

[How to resolve issues with Toolbox items](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18574)

There is an alternate by manually adding them by creating a new DevExpress Toolbox Tab and dragging all the DLLs from DevExpress installation folder in Program Files. check the steps here - [How to use DevExpress components with Express versions of Visual Studio](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18095)

Hint from: [No Toolbox created on Visual Studio 2013](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q532206)
*If nothing work for you then as you said Visual Studio 2013 was installed after DevExpress components. In this case, the simplest way to add our controls to the toolbox is to reinstall them. Alternatively, you can select the "**Repair**" option.*

Hope this help..

Comment: Yes, the 3rd paragraph solved my problem. I was thinking a utility tool should be installed with the DevExpress for this situation and seeking this tool.
   But simply, as you said, i went to Start->Control Panel->Programs and Feature->DevExpress Components 13.2, then clicked Uninstall/Change, then repair the product. It is OK now, thank you.